# 2d normal distribution c++

Tags: c++, boost, random, normal-distribution

### Edit: 4 Years later

In case anyone sumbles over here with a similar issue, **no** I never managed to resolve this problem to my satisfaction.

If you're having problems understanding what the issue **had been**, it had to do with my fear that there would be a similar distortion to generating a **normal distribution** of points around a center on a 2d plane using polar coordinates, to the distortion that is encountered when generating a uniform distribution of points in a circle around a point using polar coordinates. See [here](http://www.anderswallin.net/2009/05/uniform-random-points-in-a-circle-using-polar-coordinates/) for the distortion I was reffering to.

For me the solution was just to disscuss with my client what exactly they wanted, and for them it was more important to ensure that the distances were correct then to make sure the distribution was correct radially, which given the deadline we were on at the time meant that was the end of it.

---

### Original Post Follows:

So, my math knowledge is limited to a 3 year old high-school diploma, so I guess that this question's been answered before, but not in terms I can understand.

I've been asked to take an algorithm we use at our company, which previously generated uniformly distributed 2d points within a circle, with one that generates points within a normal distribution from a central point.

Previously I'd been using [this method](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26714) to calculate the x and y values of a point when it was a uniform distribution, with boost being my stand in for C#'s random generation algorithms.

I'd really appreciate any help here, preferably using boost (getting new external libs approved for use here is a pain), as I said, my math skills are pretty horrendous, so even if someone could point me in the direction of some other post about this issue, with some layman's terms to get me situated there, that would be great.

Comment: If you just need random values for coordinates generated, look at the standard library's `<random>` header.

Comment: Won't just generating both x and y values separately create a bias for points nearer to the center as they did in the linked to example?

Comment: Why not just port [this](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/26714) answer into c++? The author already gave a solution for generating uniform points.

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm looking for a normal distribution, not a uniform distribution.

Comment: Use `std::normal_distribution` instead of a uniform distribution, and the square root solution will remove the extant bias towards the center.

Comment: Wouldn't the square-root solution mess with normal distribution?

Comment: Without the square-root solution, all the points have a normal distribution towards the center of the circle. If you add a normal distribution on top of that, you now have two distributions interacting and it could get weird. The square root solution negates the normal distribution caused by points clustering at the center. You are left with just the distribution you added. It's like `A` is the tendency for points to group at the center and `B` is the normal-dist you want to have. Putting them together gives you `AB`, but the square-root solution inverts `A`, leaving you with `AB/A`, or `B`.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3):

From the problem statement I'd intuitively go with normal distributions for both X and Y.

But since the comment threads seems to suggest that this is not what was intended - let me guess what **was** intended:

Perhaps you are looking for a points *with **distances** to the centre* that form a normal distribution.

In that case, view the problem in vector form:

- using a single normal distribution for the distance distribution
- using a uniform distribution to select the angle [0, 360) deg

Now it's garden variety trigonometry to calculate the target point from center + vector

Comment: The issue with the solution you've presented, is that to my understanding, you are creating a significant bias towards the central point were working from, as had happened in the post I linked to in the question when using a uniform distribution.

Comment: How do you reckon this? What metric are you checking the distribution of? That's an issue with the question, really.